# OpenGL performance on rendering "virtual gallery" (textures)

Tags: performance, opengl

I have a considerable (120-240) amount of 640x480 images that will be displayed as textured flat surfaces (4 vertex polygons) in a 3D environment. About 30-50% of them will be visible in a given frame. It is possible for them to crossover. Nothing else will be present in the environment.

The question is - will the modern and/or few-years-old (lets say Radeon 9550) GPU cope with that, and what frame rate can I expect? I aim for 20FPS, but 30-40 would be nice. Would changing the resolution to 320x240 make it more probable to happen?

I do not have any previous experience with performance issues of 3D graphics on modern GPUs, and unfortunately I must make a design choice. I don't want to waste time on doing something that couldn't have worked :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have RGB textures, that would be 640*480*3*120 Bytes = 105 MB minimum of texture data, which should fit in VRAM of more recent graphics cards without swapping, so this wont be of an issue. However, texture lookups might get a bit problematic but this is hard to judge for me without trying. Given that you only need to process 50% of 105 MB, that is about 50 MB (very rough estimate) while targetting 20 FPS means 20*50MB/sec = about 1GB/sec. This should be possible to throughput even on older hardware.

Reading the specs of an older Radeon 9600 XT, it says peak fill-rate of 2000Mpixels/sec and if i'm not mistake you require far less than 100Mpixels/sec. Peak memory b/w is specified with 9.6GB/s, while you'd need about 1 GB/s (as explained above).

It would argue that this should be possible, if done correctly - esp. current hardware should have not problem at all.

Anyways, you should simply try out: Loading some random 120 textures and displaying them in some 120 quads can be done in very few lines of code with hardly any effort.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you should realize that the dimensions of textures should normally be powers of two, so if you can change them something like 512x256 (for example) would be a better starting point.

From that, you can create MIPmaps of the original, which are simply versions of the original scaled down by powers of two, so if you started with 512x256, you'd then create versions at 256x128, 128x64, 64x32, 32x16, 16x8, 8x4, 4x2, 2x1 and 1x1. When you've done this, OpenGL can/will select the "right" one for the size it'll show up at in the final display. This generally reduces the work (and improves quality) in scaling the texture to the desired size.

The obvious sticking point with that would be running out of texture memory. If memory serves, in the 9550 timeframe you could probably expect 256 MB of on-board memory, which would be about sufficient, but chances are pretty good that *some* of the textures would be in system RAM. That overflow would probably be fairly small though, so it probably won't be terribly difficult to maintain the kind of framerate you're hoping for. If you were to add a lot more textures, however, it would eventually become a problem. In that case, reducing the original size by 2 in each dimension (for example) would reduce your memory requirement by a factor of 4, which would make fitting them into memory a *lot* easier.

Comment: Neither power-of-two nor mip-maps are required for this to work. Clearly, both have their benefits, but also their drawbacks and it depends on the exact problem the OP likes to solve whether their use is suggested.

Comment: @zerm: Power of two sizes are necessary for some cards, especially older ones. MIPmaps may not be necessary, but if framerate is a concern, they can be extremely helpful.

Comment: as of OpenGL 2.1 this should be no more problem, which is out some time (I am not sure if it was OpenGL 1.6, 2.0 or 2.1)

Comment: @soxs0609389: yes, but on some cards of the vintage he's talking about, NPOT textures are rendered in software instead of hardware, which reduces the framerate quite a bit...